# error while building handbrake cli on centos 6 (64)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, handbrake

I need to install handbrake cli on CentOS 6 (64) and found this guide for CentOS6
http://www.dandev.com/2013/10/install-handbrake-cli-v0-9-9-centos-6-4/. Unfortunatly, it would not build. The build log file reports these two failuers:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
find: xcodebuild...(fail) not found
find: lipo...(fail) not found
...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
time end: Sun Sep  1 07:04:08 2013
duration: 8 seconds (8.49s)
result: FAILURE (code 2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build is finished!
You may now cd into ./build and examine the output.
```

These are not available to "#yum" or "#yum search" as xcodebuild or lipo. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER: Download the source code directly from the website instead of checking it out from the SVN repo.

LONG STORY:

I was getting this same error on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 during the make process. When I continued anyway and:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

I got:

```
========================= Installation results ===========================
/bin/cp ./HandBrakeCLI /usr/local/bin/HandBrakeCLI
/bin/cp: cannot stat ‘./HandBrakeCLI’: No such file or directory
make: *** [test.install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
```

I tried this several times with different options. Eventually I tried downloading the v0.9.9 source code from HandBrake's site instead of checking it out of the SVN repo; worked fine. I also verified this on another machine running Debian 7 "Wheezy".